# How do i make this JSON structure work as intended?

Tags: python, json

I have some data from a project where the variables can change from motorcycle and car. I need to get the name out of them and that value is inside the variable.

This is not the data i will be using but it has the same structure, the "official" data is some persional information so i changed it to some random values. I can not change the structure of the JSON data since this is the way the serveradmins decided to structure it for some reason.

This is my python code:

```
import json
with open('exampleData.json') as j:
    data = json.load(j)

name = 0
Vehicle = 0
for x in data:
    print(data['persons'][x]['name'])
    for i in data['persons'][x]['things']["Vehicles"]:
        print(data['persons'][x]['things']['Vehicles'][i]['type']['name'])
    print("\n")
```

This is my Json data i extracted from the file "ExampleData.json"(sorry for long but it is kinda complex and necessary to understand the problem):

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Sven Svensson",
      "things": {
        "House": "apartment",
        "Vehicles": [
          {
            "id": "46",
            "type": {
              "name": "Kawasaki ER6N",
              "type": "motorcyle"
            },
            "Motorcycle": {
              "plate": "aaa111",
              "fields": {
                "brand": "Kawasaki",
                "status": "in shop"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "44",
            "type": {
              "name": "BMW m3",
              "type": "Car"
            },
            "Car": {
              "plate": "bbb222",
              "fields": {
                "brand": "BMW",
                "status": "in garage"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Eric Vivian Matthews",
      "things": {
        "House": "House",
        "Vehicles": [
          {
            "id": "44",
            "type": {
              "name": "Volvo XC90",
              "type": "Car"
            },
            "Car": {
              "plate": "bbb222",
              "fields": {
                "brand": "Volvo",
                "status": "in garage"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to print out something like this :

```
Sven Svensson
Bmw M3
Kawasaki ER6n

Eric Vivian Matthews
Volvo XC90
```

but i get this error:

```
    print(data['persons'][x]['name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I found my solution.
I need to do this:

`for x in range(len(data)):`
I need to do that for both of the loops

Comment: No you don't. That is almost never the right thing to do in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
for person in data["persons"]:
    for vehicle in person["things"]["vehicles"]:
        print(vehicle["type"]["name"])
        type = vehicle["type"]["type"]
        print(vehicle[type]["plate"])
```

Comment: Thanks, is it any way that you can get the plate too? that seems to be my problem now.

Comment: That's a bit trickier because it involves a double lookup, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Python for loop does not return the key but rather an object here:

```
for x in data:
```

Referencing an object as key

```
print(data['persons'][x]['name'])
```

Is causing the error

What you need is to use the returning json object and iterate over them like so:

```
for x in data['persons']:
print(x['name'])
for vehicle in x['things']['Vehicles']:
    print(vehicle['type']['name'])
print('\n')
```